# j2me httpconnection not working in samsung devices

Tags: java-me

I try to create Asynchronous(non-blocking) request in my J2me application.
my httpconnection is running perfectly in all nokia devices
but in samsung devices sometime it does- create connection.

code is:

```
    httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(uri);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-1.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");
    respCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();// code break here
```

this code is running perfectly in nokia devices 
but i am facing this issue in samsung devices.

Comment: How does your code breaks? Does it throws an exception?

Comment: which device you are using ?

Comment: Yes this throws IOException in this line hrespCode = httpConn.getResponseCode(); i am using samsung rex 60

Comment: This is sorted out this problem was because if http Request URL length. Please manage your data in Request header or best approach is to use HttpPost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was because of http Request **URL length** handling i.e. it varies from phone to phone. On this particular series phone max http URL length was very low so i have managed my data in Request header or best approach is to use HttpPost.